# How to make this 2 pic in the middle？

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

can I know How to make the 2 pic align to the page center horizontally?？ only using HTML and CSS only..

I using this code now, but cannot..

```css
#product .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPs6X.jpg)

Comment: Please, provide HTML code.

Comment: Welcome on SO :) . I turned your code sample into a snippet. You can edit it and add anything than can demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Just use a parent container with display flex for that

Answer (score 1):

use `justify-content: center;`

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>The justify-content Property</h1>

<p>The "justify-content: center;" aligns the flex items at the center of the container:</p>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use display flex for the parent justify-content: center

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
  max-width: 1140px;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  padding: 15px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 260px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that...

```
#product {
  width: 600px;
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
    justify-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
     img {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
     }
  }
}
```

Set the number of columns and align in the center of the container.